# How to change DOM as 'if/else' statements are true individually, and also set variable to true if all if statements are true?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, if-statement, submit

Wasn't sure how to phrase this question as per usual.

I've been working on this password validation for a while (few previous questions on it) and I'm getting closer.

I have an html list showing rules for a password:

```
<form id="form-password-change" method="post" action="/notrelevantrightnow">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-username">{{label_username}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="input-username" name="username" class="required" value="{{username}}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="password-info">
        <ul>
            <li id="length" class="invalid">Password must be 8 characters</li>
            <li id="letter" class="invalid">Password must contain 3 letters</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-password">{{label_new_password}}</label>
        <div class="controls field">
            <input type="password" id="input-password" name="password" placeholder="{{label_password}}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-wide btn-primary">Send Request</button>
</form>
```

I add a class of 'valid' to each rule (

) in a list as the value of a password field passes some validation.  This is all great.  As each rule is passed, the text for that rule turns green.

However, I also need a variable to be set to true ONLY if multiple if conditions are true.
Example:  If the password is longer than 7 characters and it contains at least 3 letters, var pwdValid = true.

As it is, I have to set pwdValid = false on the else condition (which I didn't expect I would have to), and then as soon as I add another 'if' validation, once it validates the previous condition is forgotten!  So if you type 3 letters and submit, the console shows it as valid, despite the fact that the other condition (minimum 8 characters) is not met.

Here's my JS:

```
$(function(){

    var pwdInput = $('#form-password-change #input-password');

    var pwdValid = false;

    function validatePwdStrength(){

        var pwdValue = $(pwdInput).val(); // This works because when it's called it's called from the pwdInput, see end

        // Validate the length
        if (pwdValue.length > 7) {
            $('#form-password-change #length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            pwdValid = true;
        } else {
            $('#form-password-change #length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        pwdValid = false; // Had to add this in or it remains true if it passes the if case and then you change the field so it fails.
        }

        // RegExp
        // Validate number of letters letters
        if ( /([^a-z]*[a-z]){3,}/i.test(pwdValue) ) {
            $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            pwdValid = true; // As soon as I add this one, my previous if cases are forgotten.
        } else {
            $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            pwdValid = false;
        }
    };

    function validatePwdValid(){
        if (pwdValid == true) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('Password Validated');
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('Password Failed');
        }
    };

    pwdInput.bind('change keyup input', validatePwdStrength); // Keyup is a bit unpredictable
    $('#form-password-change').submit(validatePwdValid);
});
```

I might explode if I don't fix this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.  Basically we'll initialize to false, then on the first check set to true if it passes.. On subsequent checks set it to `pwdValid && true`  so if it ever fails it will continue to report false.

```
function validatePwdStrength(){

        var pwdValue = $(pwdInput).val(); // This works because when it's called it's called from the pwdInput, see end

        pwdValid = false; //start out false;

        // Validate the length
        if (pwdValue.length > 7) {
            $('#form-password-change #length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            pwdValid = true;
        } else {
            $('#form-password-change #length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');

        }

        // RegExp
        // Validate number of letters letters
        if ( /([^a-z]*[a-z]){3,}/i.test(pwdValue) ) {
            $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            pwdValid = pwdValid && true; // As soon as I add this one, my previous if cases are forgotten.
        } else {
            $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');

        }
    };
```

Comment: This is really great @lucuma, works well.  I just have 1 problem remaining.  If the validation is true, e.g. both fields pass the validation then pwdValid gets set to true.  However, if you then change the value in the password box, it still considers it set to true?  [There's a fiddle here if it helps?](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/VSYr6/1/)

Comment: On your fiddle I entered enough characters to set the validations to green and then I started to delete them and the validations were removed.. I'm not following what the issue is?

Comment: Yeah the adding and removing of the class works fine.  I've added an alert when you submit the form in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/VSYr6/2/) that shows how the pwdValid is set to true when it should be false in the above scenario.

Comment: I think you missed part of the answer.  You need to set pwdValid to false in the function at the top.  See the comment where it says `// start out false`  I've updated your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/VSYr6/3/

Comment: Ah yes I did miss that, and then I was setting it false by retyping `var pwdValid = false` instead of `pwdValid = false`.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I have just realised that this only works for 2 if cases.  Is there a different technique if there were even more rules? I wrongly made an assumption that if I had it working for two, I was all sorted to carry on adding more http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/VSYr6/6/

Comment: Please see my answer.  Remove the `var` from the pwdValid *inside* the function.

Comment: Sorry, I had done that but made a mistake mixing versions on jsfiddle.  I couldn't get it working locally, then suddenly it did.  Sorry again and thanks, again.